# momentum and Kinetic Energy

Tags: momentum, kinetic-theory

Make some general statements about momentum and kinetic energy conservation.
So, I is this correct?

Two objects of varying mass have the same momentum. The least massive of the two objects will have the greatest kinetic energy.

What other statements can be added?

Comment: What is your question?  I don't understand what is being asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a list question which aren't very good for SE. Here is a proof of your statement:

$m_1v_1 = m_2v_2$

$\dfrac{m_1}{m_2} = \dfrac {v_2}{v_1}$

Let us assume that $m_1$ < $m_2$

$\dfrac{(m_1)^2}{(m_2)^2} = \dfrac {(v_2)^2}{(v_1)^2} < 1$

$v_1$ must be greater than $v_2$

The only case the energy of a higher velocity is beaten is shown by the graphs below:

[image]

This graph shows that it only happens for fractional velocities.

Well, (though it seems like creating) we can finish this proof by defining new units. A half-kg is a single unit worth 0.5 kg. This covers the fractional values of v not covered in our proof.